# Django pop up modal after Inserting/updating data

Tags: python, django

I've been searching in google and SO about pop up message when user submit but that doesnt work when i apply it to my code, I just want that if the user update/insert data, a pop up modal message appears

I have this form in my html

```
<form method="post" id="myform" class="myform" style="width: 100%" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <table  id="blacklistgrids" border="2px">
    <tr>
        {% for v in table.0 %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
                <th id="thupdate">{{v}}</th>
            {% else %}
                <th ><input type="text" name="updatedate" value="{{ v }}"></th>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <th  hidden></th>
        <th data-id='headerss' id='headerave'>Average</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    {% for row in table|slice:"1:" %}
        <tr class="tr2update">
            <td><input type="text" value="{{row.0}}" name="students" hidden>{% for n in teacherStudents %}{{n.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users}}{% endfor %}</td>
             <td class="tdupdate" hidden><input type="text" hidden></td>
            {% for teacher in students %}
            <input type="hidden"  name="id"   value="{{teacher.id}}"/>
            <td>
                <input type="text"  data-form-field="{{teacher.id}}" name="oldgrad" class="oldgrad"  value="{{teacher.Grade|floatformat:'2'}}"/>
            </td>
            {% endfor %}
            {% for avg in average %}
            <td data-id='row' id="ans"><input type='number' class='averages' step="any" name="average" value="{{average.average_grade|floatformat:'2'}}" readonly/></td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
     {% endfor %}
    </tbody>

</table>
    <div class="buttons">
    <input type="submit" value="&nearrow;&nbsp;Update" class="save"   formaction="/updategrades/">
    </div>
        </form>

<script>
if (typeof jqXhr.success != 'undefined') {
    $('#thanksModal').modal('show');
} else {
    $('#myform').html(jqXhr);
}
</script>
```

and this is my views.py

```
import json
def updategrades(request):
    /some logic/
   return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"success":True}), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: Looks like you're already using jQuery so I'll suggest a jQuery-based solution. You'll have to bind to the submit event of the form first. Link: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use ajax and bootstrap modal,
crate a general modal somewhere in your html page(I usually have it in my base.html so it will be included in all pages) then submit your from by using ajax then ajax will provide success or error function regarding the response will receive from server-side. put that message in the modal. an example is:

## somewhere inside base.html

```
    <!-- Info General modal -->
    <div id="general_modal" class="modal fade " >
      <div class="modal-dialog ">
        <div class="modal-content ">
          <div class="modal-header bg-info">
            <h6 class="modal-title">Info header</h6>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- Empty will be field by Js -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /info General modal -->
```

## js and ajax function

```
$("#your-form").on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
var ajax_link = this.getAttribute("data-ajax-link");
var target = this.getAttribute("data-target");
var title = this.getAttribute("data-modal-title");
var size = this.getAttribute("data-modal-size");
var bg = this.getAttribute("data-modal-content-bg");
// $(target+" .modal-body").load(ajax_link);
$.ajax({
    url:ajax_link,
    type:'POST',
    // data: $("#your-form-feilds").serialize(),

    success: function (response){
        $(target+" .modal-body").html(response);
    },
    /*
    error:function (response){
        new PNotify({
            title: 'oops',
            text:' Unable to load',
            type: 'error'
        });
    }
   */
});

$(target+" .modal-content").addClass(bg);
$(target+" .modal-title").html(title);
$(target+" .modal-dialog").removeClass().addClass("modal-dialog");
$(target+" .modal-dialog").addClass(size);
```

});

## html form

```
<form action="." method="post" id="your-form" class="btn btn-info  modal-ajax-load"
                        data-ajax-link="url"
                        data-toggle="modal"
                        data-modal-title="tilte"
                        data-target="#general_modal">
```

ofcurse you need to modify this answer to create the functions you need